# How to convert String[] to Map with array index as summed value in java lambda?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I have the following

```
new ConstructStateMachine(new String[] {
      "a", "b", "c", "aa", "d", "b"
}, 1, 5);
```

And I would like to convert this array to **`Map<String, Integer>`**.

So that the string will the string element in the array as key in my map, and the value will be the index of the array as list of integers as value.

I also need to keep duplicate keys, but of course that's impossible in Map, but the solution is that we ignore duplicate keys, but we sum up the values of duplicate key as, and instead of having List we have Integer as value with sum of all values for duplicate keys.

Say we have this table:

```
indices | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3  | 4 | 5 |
item    | a | b | c | aa | d | b |
value   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5 | 6 |
```

So our Map should keep the following:

```
// pseudo-code
Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<>(
   ("b"  => 8) // because "b" appeared in index 1 and 5
   ("c"  => 3)
   ("aa" => 4)
   ("d"  => 5)
);
```

My Incomplete solution:

```
Map < String, List < Integer >> table = new HashMap < > ();


// I thought of doing an intersection of two arrays and get the value from there
// but that just made things more complicated
String[] a = (Arrays.stream(dictionary)
  .filter(x - > Arrays.stream(newDis)
    .anyMatch(y - > Objects.equals(y, x))
  )
).toArray(String[]::new);


// in here, I tried looping and created the value that starts from 1 to 6, rather than
// from 0 to 5
IntStream.range(0, this.newDis.length).forEach(idx - > {
  List<Integer> currentValue = table.computeIfAbsent(newDis[idx], k - > new ArrayList<>());
  currentValue.add(idx + 1);
});
```

But I simply cant convert my string array to `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: lambda seems like a bad fit for this task.  It feels like you have a screwdriver and are attempting to use it as an x-box controller.    Consider writing a method.

Comment: well put haha. Sorry, I dont mind if its lambda or good old OOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "aa", "d", "b"};
Map<String, Integer> result =
    IntStream.range(0, array.length)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> array[i], i -> i + 1, Integer::sum));
```

or, with a simple loop, which makes the code more redable and intuitive, IMO:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.merge(array[i], i + 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Well put JB! Thanks for quick response :)

Comment: Just a side note, you can declare an array as simple as `String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "aa", "d", "b"};`, without the `new String[]`…